# Ace - How do I force a new line after a specified number of characters (columns)?

Tags: ace-editor

I am using Ace IDE and I want to make it force a new line when the user enters a certain amount of characters on that line. I do not want it to create a new line as such, just return the cursor onto the next line, keeping the same line number. similar to this style:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `editor.setOption("wrap", 80)`.